# D3 v3 line generator interpolate cardinal draws straight lines

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to make a  static network of sorts using d3 v3. I want to draw curved lines between two nodes, similar to the [collapsible tree example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). I've set the line generator interpolate to "cardinal", but the lines come out straight. Step-before and step-after both work fine.

Here's my js:

```
var arr1 = [
  {id:0,name:"A",depends:[3,4,5]},
  {id:1,name:"B",depends:[4,5]},
  {id:2,name:"C",depends:[3,5]},
];

var arr2 = [
  {id:3,name:"D",depends:[8,10,11]},
  {id:4,name:"E",depends:[9,10,12]},
  {id:5,name:"F",depends:[12]},
  {id:6,name:"G",depends:[8,9]},
  {id:7,name:"H",depends:[12]},
];

var arr3 = [
  {id:8,name:"I",depends:[13,14]},
  {id:9,name:"J",depends:[15,16]},
  {id:10,name:"K",depends:[17]},
  {id:11,name:"L",depends:[15,13]},
  {id:12,name:"M",depends:[16]},
];

var arr4 = [
  {id:13,name:"N",depends:[14]},
  {id:14,name:"O",depends:[]},
  {id:15,name:"P",depends:[]},
  {id:16,name:"Q",depends:[]},
  {id:17,name:"R",depends:[]},
];


var svg = d3.select("svg");

//set node positions
arr1.forEach(function(node,i) {
  node.x = 300;
  node.y = (1000/(arr1.length+1))*(i+1);
});
arr2.forEach(function(node,i) {
  node.x = 600;
  node.y = (1000/(arr2.length+1))*(i+1);
});
arr3.forEach(function(node,i) {
  node.x = 900;
  node.y = (1000/(arr3.length+1))*(i+1);
});
arr4.forEach(function(node,i) {
  node.x = 1200;
  node.y = (1000/(arr4.length+1))*(i+1);
});

//set path start and end points
var nodes = arr1.concat(arr2.concat(arr3.concat(arr4)));
nodes.forEach(function(n) {
  for(let i=0; i<n.depends.length; ++i) {
    //[[start x, start y],[end x, and y]]
    n.depends[i] = [[n.x,n.y],[nodes[n.depends[i]].x,nodes[n.depends[i]].y]];
  }
});


var g = svg.selectAll("g").data(nodes).enter().append("g");

var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line().interpolate("cardinal").x(function(d) { return d[0]; }).y(function(d) { return d[1]; }).tension(0.5);
g.selectAll("path").data(function(d) {return d.depends}).enter().append("path").attr("d",function(d) {
  if(d != undefined) {  return lineGenerator(d);}
});

g.append("circle").attr("cx",function(d){return d.x;}).attr("cy",function(d){return d.y;}).attr("r",10);

g.append("text").attr("x", function(d) {return d.x;}).attr("y", function(d) {return d.y;}).attr("dx", "1em").attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) {return d.name;});
```

[What's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grw0q.png)

[What I'm trying to do (in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCpCr.png)

Maybe I should try to use the diagonal function in the collapsible tree example? I appreciate your help

**EDIT:**

I switched to the diagonal function in the collapsible tree example, which gets me mostly to where I want to be.

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
.projection(function(d) {
  return [d.y, d.x];
});

g.selectAll("path").data(function(d) {return d.depends}).enter().append("path").attr("d",function(d) {
  if(d != undefined) { return diagonal({source:{y:d[0][0],x:d[0][1]},target:{y:d[1][0],x:d[1][1]}});}
});
```

[Diagonal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXpd6.png)

But I would still like to know why the cardinal interpolator was not working?

Comment: If your path is between two nodes and has no other points, a cardinal spline between those two points will be a straight line - which way would it bend and why? You could add an offset middle point manually based on the position of the other two points and then pass these three points to a line generator that uses a d3 curve.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I misunderstood what a cardinal line is. Thank you!